# Delphi boolean variable values

Tags: delphi, initialization, boolean

Why is that in `Delphi` Boolean variable initialized in `global scope is false` and variable initialized in `local scope is true`?

Can we change any of the default values so that `both (global and local variables)` have the same values on initialization?

sample code

```
    unit Unit1;

    interface

    uses
      Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, 
      Controls, Forms,Dialogs, StdCtrls;

    type
      TForm1 = class(TForm)
        Button1: TButton;
        Label1: TLabel;
        Label2: TLabel;
        procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
      private
        { Private declarations }
      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;

    var
      Form1: TForm1;
      bool1:boolean;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
     bool :boolean;
    begin
     if bool then
       label1.Caption:='true'
     else
       label1.caption:='false';
     if bool1 then
       label2.Caption:='true'
     else
       label2.caption:='false';

    end;

    end.
```

This displays me the result as

[image]

where `true is label1 and false is label2`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Local variables are actually not initialized, but global variables and object fields are initialized to zero (which means 'false' for boolean variables).

Therefore you always have to initialize local variables yourself, compiler even generates a warning if you don't.

You should also check out [Delphi documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variables) on variables.

Comment: you are right it gives warning, but its value is `true` by default

Comment: @Shirish11: No, that is just what it happens to be in this case. Move your code somewhere else, add code to your project and it could change. **Don't** rely on it. Uninitialized means that you simply cannot predict what the value will be unless you initialize it yourself.

Comment: @MarjanVenema is it that when u have local variables it is not `initialized to zero(false in this case)` and has some garbage value assigned to it hence `non zero(true)`

Comment: It just happens to be that there are much more possible values for true than for false (=0). So it is more likely that you encounter a true as a false for an uninitialized Boolean.

Comment: Uwe Raabe. No. 0 is false, 1 is true, the rest is undefined. Relying on non (0,1) being true is therefore also dangerous, and might depend on compiler, version and the way you test. If you want <>0 is true behaviour, use bytebool.

Comment: @Marco: If you have an uninitialized Boolean variable (which has the size of a byte) you end up with 256 possible bit patterns in this variable from which only one will give FALSE while 255 will give TRUE. If you set the variable to FALSE or TRUE it will only have the values 0 and 1, but then it is not uninitialized anymore.

Comment: I repeat, for boolean only 0 or 1 is valid. It might be that codegeneration _may_ also process 2..255 as true, because it is cheaper, but that is not guaranteed (see "Simple types" in the help, nowhere is said that 2..255 is true, while it _IS_ said for the bytebool types).  And that is exactly what "undefined" is, a compiler is allowed to select the cheapest case there.  A classic example is GTK gboolean which must be 0 or 1 otherwise assertions will happen. The "boolean" types match this perfectly, the bytebool types will lead to assertions. For this case FPC also has added boolean16/32

Comment: @Marco, my statement that TRUE is more likely for an uninitialized variable is just a statistical observation. It was meant as an explanation why Shirish11 is seeing TRUE as a "default" for local variables. This might be specific for the Delphi compiler, but that is just what this question asked for.

Answer (score 2):

Global variables are always initialized to zero - in boolean that means false. Local variables in procedures and methods are not initialized at all. You need to assign value to them yourself.